# How to skip/ignore a specific position (on a list) within a loop, in C language?

Tags: c, loops

A beginner in C language, I have to find the second and third smallest numbers from a list of N numbers.

```
void MenordeN (int N, int lista[100], int *c,int *posicion)
{
int menor,cont;
menor=lista[0];
for (cont=1;cont<N;cont++)
{
    if (lista[cont]<menor)
    {
        menor=lista[cont];
        *posicion= cont+1;
    }
}
*c=menor;
```

}

```
int main()
{
int lista[100],menor, n, con,res,pos;
printf("Ingrese el valor de N: \n");
scanf("%i",&n);
printf("Ingrese %i numeros: \n",n);
for (con=0;con<n;con++)
{
    scanf("%i",&lista[con]);
}
MenordeN(n,lista,&res,&pos);
printf("El elemento menor es: %i en posicion %i",res,pos);        //*res is the answer(smallest number)
```

### As of now: void MenordeN is to find the smallest number and its position. Main calls void MenordeN. However, how do I skip posicion[res] so that I can call void MenordeN again to find the second smallest number?

```
int low = lista[0],m,i,idx; // init with first array element.
m = low;
for( i=0; i<3; ++i)
{
    for(idx=0; idx<=100; ++idx)
    {
        if (lista[idx]>low)
        {
            m = MIN(m,lista[idx]);
        }
    }
}
printf("\n3rd lowest value is %d\n", m);

return 0;
```

### ----->This just prints the first value entered, not the third smallest.

```
int main()
{
int lista[100],menor, n, con, res, pos,resp;
printf("Ingrese el valor de N: \n");
scanf("%i",&n);
printf("Ingrese %i numeros: \n",n);
for (con=0;con<n;con++)
{
    scanf("%i",&lista[con]);
}
MenordeN(n,lista,&res,&pos);
printf("El elemento menor es: %i en posicion %i",res,pos);
res=NULL;
MenordeN(n,lista,&resp,&pos);
printf("\nEl segundo elemento menor es: %i en posicion %i",resp,pos);
return 0;
```

---------------> I know this is wrong, but isn't there something simpler like res=NULL or lista[res]==NULL? My teacher wouldn't expect anything too complicated because we are still in programming I.

Comment: My teacher doesn't want the program to sort out the numbers in order. But how can I skip the position of lista[res] so that when I call void again, the position and its number won't be included?

Comment: Or can I just null that position with lista[res] ==NULL?

Comment: `lista[pos]=INT_MAX;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, why pos and not res(smallest number)? Would I have to add #ifndef INT_MAX
#define MAX(X,Y) ((X) < (Y) ? (X) : (Y))
#endif

Comment: `res` is not indexed to a minimum value. (and maybe on your code `lista[pos-1]=INT_MAX;` . `INT_MAX` is defined macro in `<limits.h>`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I still don't get how to use it, sorry. Is there another way to take out that first small value? Something like 
     do
     {
         MenordeN(n,lista,&resp,&posi);
    }while (lista[con]!=lista[res]);

Comment: `res` isn't index. and The same number of times when you call with `lista` is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

your list is technical an array. You can sort that (e.g. with qsort from stdlib.h) and access the n-th element from both sides: largest and smallest.

qsort is defined like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

and to get the 3rd smallest element you access the sorted list (that is an array) like this:

```
printf("3rd element: %d\n", lista[2]);
```

The index starts at 0, not a 1.

If you don't want to sort the array, than you can do it like this (pseudo code)

```
#include <limits.h>
...
#ifndef MIN
#define MIN(X,Y) ((X) < (Y) ? (X) : (Y))
#endif

int low = lista[0]; // init with first array element.
for(int idx=0; idx<=100; ++idx) {
    low = MIN(low, lista[idx]);
}

int m = low;
for(int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
    for(int idx=0; idx<=100; ++idx) {
    if (lista[idx]>low) {
        m = MIN(m,lista[idx]);
    }
}
printf("3rd lowest value is %d\n", m);
```

Comment: A message appears saying that INT_MIN is undeclared.

Comment: @user3053042 have you added the #include <limits.h>?

Comment: Yes - but the message now reads "undefined reference to INT_MIN. Is there another way to ignore the smallest number the next time void MenordeN is used??

Comment: in that case I added a workaround. If you post the complete error, than we can go back to the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#include <limits.h>

...
MenordeN(n,lista,&res,&pos);
printf("El elemento menor es: %i en posicion %i",res,pos);
lista[pos-1]=INT_MAX;
MenordeN(n,lista,&resp,&pos);
printf("\nEl segundo elemento menor es: %i en posicion %i",resp,pos);
```